# No product to add in Facebook App's "Add a Product" page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I've been trying to do the tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started but I immediately get stuck on Step 2 because there's no product under "Add a Product" list as seen on the screenshot below.

[Facebook App Dashboard - Add a Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P43y.png)

I've done the following but still no luck:

- Google
- Search SO but wasn't able to find an issue like this
- Disabled adblocker
- Created a new account solely to use in Facebook Developers site

Anyone can point me to the right direction? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

---

Edit: Someone's having the same issue so to anyone else in the same boat, might be best to follow this: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2598338917071430/